# C++ vector of objects

Tags: c++, oop

I'm learning the concept of OOP , i made simple program that reads names of students and store them inside vector of objects ; a created a class students

```
class student{
public:


        student(string,int);

        string getName() const{
            return name;
        }

        int getAge() const{
            return age;
        }


private:
    string name;
    int age;


};

student::student(string name,int age){
    name=name;
    age=age;

}
```

and in main i read lines as

```
vector<student> myClass;
    string var;
    int index=0;
    while(getline(cin,var)){

        student newStudent(var,index);
        myClass.push_back(newStudent);

     }
    for( int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
        cout << myClass[i].getName() << endl;
    }

    return 0;
```

But as i want to print names ,it only prints blank lines , I tried to print name right after initializing class in while loop and it also print blank lines. I'm quite new to OOP and i do not see any problem here, what did i overlook? Where is a bug in my little program?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
student::student(string name,int age){
    name=name;
    age=age;
}
```

`name` and `age` are the parameters here, right? So you're assigning the parameters to themselves (which does nothing) and leaving the member variables unchanged.

You could change the names, so they don't have the same names:

```
student::student(string name2,int age2){
    name=name2;
    age=age2;
}
```

or use `this->` to refer to the member variables explicitly:

```
student::student(string name,int age){
    this->name=name;
    this->age=age;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try writing
`this->name =  name;`
and 
`this->age=age;`
in the constructor

Answer (score 1):

The parameters in your constructor overshadow your actual member variables. There are multiple ways to solve this:

1. **Use a [initialization list](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list)**
2. Rename your members, e.g to `m_name`
3. Access your members through the [`this`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/this) pointer, e.g `this->name = name`

Answer (score 0):

The specific problem is here:

```
student::student(string name,int age){
  name=name;
  age=age;
}
```

You expect the compiler to understand that one `name` is the member variable and the other `name` is the local variable, but it has no way to know this. Try this:

```
student::student(string n_name,int n_age){
  name=n_name;
  age=n_age;
}
```

The more general problem is that you tried to connect this functionality to other code (iterating in a loop, reading a file) before testing it. Your first `main` should have looked like this:

```
student S("Adam", 0);
cout << S.getName() << endl;
```